# How would I define a region with multiple holes?

Tags: regions, mesh

I would like to define a region consisting of a polygon with eight holes in it. This is essentially a stamped piece of metal with eight holes.

```
a01 = Disk[{-0.5, 1},0.1];
a02 = Disk[{-1.5, 1},0.1];
a03 = Disk[{-2.5, 1},0.1];
a04 = Disk[{-3.5, 1},0.1];
a05 = Disk[{-4.5, 1},0.1];
a06 = Disk[{-5.5, 1},0.1];
a07 = Disk[{-6.5, 1},0.1];
a08 = Disk[{-7.5, 1},0.1];

aRegion = RegionUnion[ a01,
                       a02,
                       a03,
                       a04,
                       a05,
                       a06,
                       a07,
                       a08 ];

bRegion = Polygon[ {{-12.5,6}, {12.5, 6}, {6.5, 0}, {-6.5, 0}} ];

\[CapitalOmega] = Region @ RegionDifference[aRegion, bRegion]
```

The `aRegion` is a series of eight holes.

[image: aRegion as a union of eight holes.]

The `bRegion` is a simple polygon.
[image: bRegion as a simple polygon.]

I am trying to create a polygon with eight holes.   The result of the `RegionDifference` is shown below.

[image: RegionDifference result]

Note that if I swap the parameters in the call to `RegionDifference`, I get the `bRegion` polygon without holes.

What would be the correct way to define a region that is essentially the `bRegion` polygon minus the `aRegion` holes?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You mixed up the ordering of `bRegion` and `aRegion`. Moreover, `Region` is only suitable for a quick preview; it usually does not discretize very accurately. Try `DiscretizeRegion` with variable `MaxCellMeasure` instead.

```
\[CapitalOmega] = DiscretizeRegion[RegionDifference[bRegion, aRegion], 
  MaxCellMeasure -> 0.001]
```

[image]

You may also try to specify a suitable `MeshRefinementFunction` in order to localize the refinement of the mesh around the holes.

Answer (score 8):

As Henrik has pointed out, the holes are there when the parameterization of [`RegionDifference`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionDifference.html) is correct. Sometimes having `Infix` notation in mind will help to avoid mistakes.

Another advice is to start using *contructor functions* with *parameters* defined only once (e.g. using scoping constructs like `With`) right from the start. So mind the advice: [Don't repeat yourself (DRY)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). This helps to easily "play around" with what you have done. Using a larger radius, for example, would have quickly shown that the holes are there even in the coarse output produced by `Region` but are simply to small (e.g. setting radius to 0.3 would have sufficed).

Next to discretizing there is [`RegionPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionPlot.html), which offers more control with regard to the outcome:

```
With[
  {
    r = 0.1, (* radius of holes *)
    xmin = -12.5,
    xmax = 12.5,
    ymin = 0,
    ymax = 6,
    holesX = Range[-0.5, -7.5, -1],
    holesY = 1,
    minus = RegionDifference
  }
  ,
  aRegion = RegionUnion @ Map[Disk[{#, holesY}, r] &, holesX];
  bRegion = Polygon @ { {xmin, ymax}, {xmax, ymax}, {6.5, ymin}, {-6.5, ymin} };
  Ω = bRegion ~ minus ~ aRegion; (* infix makes this more readable *)
  RegionPlot[ Evaluate @ RegionMember[ Ω, {x, y} ] 
    , {x, xmin, xmax}
    , {y, ymin, ymax}
    , AspectRatio -> (ymax - ymin)/(xmax - xmin)
    , PlotPoints -> 200
  ]
]
```

[image: RegionPlot]